# Can't create a MySQL query that generates 4 rows for each row in the table it references

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I need to create a MySQL query that generates 4 rows for each row in the table it references. I need some of the information in those rows to repeat and some to be different. In the table each row stands for one day. I need to break the day up in 6 hour increments, hence the four rows for each entry. I need to create one column which for each day will have '12AM', '6AM', '12PM', and '6PM' values and another column will have the corresponding numeric values calculated for those entries.

Thanks a lot in advance and I will really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Example data would be nice, even if it's not real, and a sample of an expected result.

Comment: Is it always going to be those four times?  You could structure the table like so:
date | 12amvalue | 6amvalue | 12pmvalue | 6pmvalue

Comment: An integer / number table (1 - n) is often used for these kind of queries, however, as you say "another column will have the corresponding numeric values calculated" are you 100% sure that those don't come from another table and we can just join on date, and GROUP BY FLOOR(HOUR(some_timestamp_column)/6 ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions. After cross joining I have a table where one column has '12AM', '6AM', '12PM' and '6PM' repeating for each day entry. Another column is supposed to have values calculated for those increments but is currently filled with NULLs. I need to fill that column with calculated values, which will come from some reference table. I don't know how to associate those calculated values with the correct time increments. I will really appreciate any ideas. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The reference table in question contains values for each day for several months broken down by hour where each hour has its own column. So, basically, I have to add the values for each 6 hour increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the query should do and calculate with the values is a bit vague, but simply generating four rows for each row in another table is straight foward:

```
Select ...
From Table
    Cross Join  (
                Select '12 AM'
                Union All Select '6 AM'
                Union All Select '12 PM'
                Union All Select '6 PM'
                ) As Times
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do an insert with a `SELECT` statement, and use `UNION` to get the 4 records. Some `SQL` pseudocode is below.

```
INSERT INTO table1
          ( clock_time
          , some_value
          )
     SELECT '12AM'
          , sum(some_value)
       FROM ref_table
      WHERE ...
  UNION ALL
     SELECT '6AM'
          , sum(some_value)
       FROM ref_table
      WHERE ...
  UNION ALL
     SELECT '12PM'
          , sum(some_value)
       FROM ref_table
      WHERE ...
  UNION ALL
     SELECT '6PM'
          , sum(some_value)
       FROM ref_table
      WHERE ...
```

Comment: Unless you put the SELECT queries inside their own set of brackets, you can only apply one ORDER BY & LIMIT clause to the entire query.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - You're always here aren't you :).  Seriously, I assumed the OP could put his conditions within each WHERE clause which would limit the queries. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: stackoverflow == Hotel California =)  It's the "4 rows from each table" that screams LIMIT clause to me.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions. After cross joining I have a table where one column has '12AM', '6AM', '12PM' and '6PM' repeating for each day entry. Another column is supposed to have values calculated for those increments but is currently filled with NULLs. I need to fill that column with calculated values, which will come from some reference table. I don't know how to associate those calculated values with the correct time increments.

I will really appreciate any ideas. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The reference table in question contains values for each day for several months broken down by hour where each hour has its own column. So, basically, I have to add the values for each 6 hour increment.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table that contain your four time-points, and join with it to get the cartesian product.

```
select *
from days, hour_increments
```

The cartesian product of two tables is the join of every row in the first table to every row in the second. For instance, if we have the tables {1, 2, 3} and {a, b, c} then the product is {1a, 1b, 1c, 2a, 2b, 2c, 3a, 3b, 3c}.

How to make sensible calculations based on that dataset is another story that depends on the data and what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you so much for your cross join suggestion. It solved part of my problem, but not all of it. After cross joining I have a table where one column has '12AM', '6AM', '12PM' and '6PM' repeating for each day entry. Another column is supposed to have values calculated for those increments but is currently filled with NULLs. I need to fill that column with calculated values, which will come from some reference table. I don't know how to associate those calculated values with the correct time increments. I will really appreciate any ideas. Thanks a lot in advance.